# Error when using Train Image classifier from OTB Toolbox Plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, error, classification

I was able to install the OTB Toolbox Plugin correctly into QGIS but I encountered a problem when I run the Train Image classifier, it returned an error:

> ERROR: Cannot find PROJ:

How can I solve this problem?